# JavaScript add transparency option to stringToColour function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This function returns a hex color from a string.  How can I have it set a transparency level as well. So I could pass in 50 or 80 as the transparency level.  I know that 50% is #80; but can't figure out how to modify the function to handle transparency.

```
var stringToColour = function (str) {
    var hash = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            hash = str.charCodeAt(i) + ((hash << 5) - hash);
        }
        var colour = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var value = (hash >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF;
            colour += ('00' + value.toString(16)).substr(-2);
        }
        return colour;
}
$('body').css('background-color', stringToColour("greenish"));
```

Comment: Why not use RGBA or HSLA colors, the last value is the opacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely maps alpha percent to its hex values following the list below:

```
100% — FF
99% — FC
98% — FA
97% — F7
96% — F5
95% — F2
94% — F0
93% — ED
92% — EB
91% — E8
90% — E6
89% — E3
88% — E0
87% — DE
86% — DB
85% — D9
84% — D6
83% — D4
82% — D1
81% — CF
80% — CC
79% — C9
78% — C7
77% — C4
76% — C2
75% — BF
74% — BD
73% — BA
72% — B8
71% — B5
70% — B3
69% — B0
68% — AD
67% — AB
66% — A8
65% — A6
64% — A3
63% — A1
62% — 9E
61% — 9C
60% — 99
59% — 96
58% — 94
57% — 91
56% — 8F
55% — 8C
54% — 8A
53% — 87
52% — 85
51% — 82
50% — 80
49% — 7D
48% — 7A
47% — 78
46% — 75
45% — 73
44% — 70
43% — 6E
42% — 6B
41% — 69
40% — 66
39% — 63
38% — 61
37% — 5E
36% — 5C
35% — 59
34% — 57
33% — 54
32% — 52
31% — 4F
30% — 4D
29% — 4A
28% — 47
27% — 45
26% — 42
25% — 40
24% — 3D
23% — 3B
22% — 38
21% — 36
20% — 33
19% — 30
18% — 2E
17% — 2B
16% — 29
15% — 26
14% — 24
13% — 21
12% — 1F
11% — 1C
10% — 1A
9% — 17
8% — 14
7% — 12
6% — 0F
5% — 0D
4% — 0A
3% — 08
2% — 05
1% — 03
0% — 00
```

Ref: https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4

Example

```js
// 00 - 0%
// 03 - 1%
// 05 - 2%
const hexAlpha = [ '00', '03', '05' ];

var stringToColour = function (str, alpha) {
    var hash = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            hash = str.charCodeAt(i) + ((hash << 5) - hash);
        }
        var colour = `#${hexAlpha[alpha]}`;
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var value = (hash >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF;
            colour += ('00' + value.toString(16)).substr(-2);
        }
        return colour;
}

// First 2 char determines alpha
console.log(stringToColour("greenish", 2));
```

Comment: But how do I integrate those in the function?  That's the problem,what do I pass in to return a transparent colour?

Comment: You pass a integer with the alpha you need, then if you store the hex values in an array with percent integer as index you're done.

Comment: Where do I pass in the integer?

Comment: like `function (str, alpha)`

Comment: and alpha goes where?

Comment: Alpha is represented by the first 2 chars, look at my example

Comment: Thanks!  Yes had just figured it out, need more coffee.

Answer (score 1):

You want to map a percent [0 - 100] to a value in the range of [0 - 255] then convert that decimal integer to a hexadecimal integer.

```
const percentToHex = (p) => {
    const percent = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, p)); // bound percent from 0 to 100
    const intValue = Math.round(p / 100 * 255); // map percent to nearest integer (0 - 255)
    const hexValue = intValue.toString(16); // get hexadecimal representation
    return hexValue.padStart(2, '0').toUpperCase(); // format with leading 0 and upper case characters
}
```

```
console.log(percentToHex(0));
console.log(percentToHex(50));
console.log(percentToHex(80));
console.log(percentToHex(100));
```

will output

```
00
80
CC
FF
```